# Keras model seems untrained after loading weights

Tags: keras

I am trying to save and restore the weights for a given model in Keras.
I am successful in saving the weights, using model.save_weights(filepath, ...) and also the weights are actually loaded. I can confirm this by saving model.get_weights() to a file, after saving and after restoring, and diffing the files that I receive that way.

However my model is just as bad as it is at the start. Is there anything I am missing?

```
def __init__(self, **args):
        # Next, we build our model. We use the same model that was described by Mnih et al. (2015).
        self.model.add(Convolution2D(32, (3, 3), strides=(1, 1)))
        self.model.add(Activation('relu'))
        self.model.add(Convolution2D(64, (3, 3), strides=(1, 1)))
        self.model.add(Activation('relu'))
        self.model.add(Convolution2D(64, (3, 3), strides=(1, 1)))
        self.model.add(Activation('relu'))
        self.model.add(Flatten())
        self.model.add(Dense(512))
        self.model.add(Activation('relu'))
        self.model.add(Dense(self.nb_actions)) #nb_actions))
        self.model.add(Activation('linear'))
        print(self.model.summary())

        if os.path.isfile("/home/abcd/model.weights"):
            self.model.load_weights("/home/abcd/model.weights")
        self.compile(Adam(lr=.00025), metrics=['mae'])
```

...

```
def compile(self, optimizer, metrics=[]):
    metrics += [mean_q]  # register default metrics

    # We never train the target model, hence we can set the optimizer and loss arbitrarily.
    self.target_model = clone_model(self.model, self.custom_model_objects)

    if os.path.isfile("/home/abcd/target_model.weights"):
        self.target_model.load_weights("/home/abcd/target_model.weights")

    self.target_model.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss='mse')
    self.model.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss='mse')

    # Compile model.
    if self.target_model_update < 1.:
        # We use the `AdditionalUpdatesOptimizer` to efficiently soft-update the target model.
        updates = get_soft_target_model_updates(self.target_model, self.model, self.target_model_update)
        optimizer = AdditionalUpdatesOptimizer(optimizer, updates)

    def clipped_masked_error(args):
        y_true, y_pred, mask = args
        loss = huber_loss(y_true, y_pred, self.delta_clip)
        loss *= mask  # apply element-wise mask
        return K.sum(loss, axis=-1)

    # Create trainable model. The problem is that we need to mask the output since we only
    # ever want to update the Q values for a certain action. The way we achieve this is by
    # using a custom Lambda layer that computes the loss. This gives us the necessary flexibility
    # to mask out certain parameters by passing in multiple inputs to the Lambda layer.
    y_pred = self.model.output
    y_true = Input(name='y_true', shape=(self.nb_actions,))
    mask = Input(name='mask', shape=(self.nb_actions,))
    loss_out = Lambda(clipped_masked_error, output_shape=(1,), name='loss')([y_true, y_pred, mask])
    ins = [self.model.input] if type(self.model.input) is not list else self.model.input
    trainable_model = Model(inputs=ins + [y_true, mask], outputs=[loss_out, y_pred])
    assert len(trainable_model.output_names) == 2
    combined_metrics = {trainable_model.output_names[1]: metrics}
    losses = [
        lambda y_true, y_pred: y_pred,  # loss is computed in Lambda layer
        lambda y_true, y_pred: K.zeros_like(y_pred),  # we only include this for the metrics
    ]

    if os.path.isfile("/home/abcd/trainable_model.weights"):
        trainable_model.load_weights("/home/abcd/trainable_model.weights")

    trainable_model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=losses, metrics=combined_metrics)
    self.trainable_model = trainable_model

    self.compiled = True
```

...

```
def final(self, state):
    "Called at the end of each game."
    # call the super-class final method
    PacmanQAgent.final(self, state)

    # did we finish training?
    if self.episodesSoFar == self.numTraining:
        # you might want to print your weights here for debugging
        "*** YOUR CODE HERE ***"
        self.training = False

        # Save the model
        self.model.save_weights("/home/abcd/model.weights", True)
        self.trainable_model.save_weights("/home/abcd/trainable_model.weights", True)
        self.target_model.save_weights("/home/abcd/target_model.weights", True)
```

Comment: This should not be the case, can you make sure, you are loading weights correctly following docs https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#savingloading-only-a-models-weights , otherwise share your code, that will help other to see the problem.

Comment: @AnkishBansal With the exception of using absolute paths, and the extension '.weights' instead of '.h5', yes. Could that be a problem?

I load the weights before compiling the model, is that the correct way of doing it?
The whole system is comprised of 3 models as can be seen here https://github.com/keras-rl/keras-rl/blob/master/rl/agents/dqn.py in the compile function

Comment: @Skusku Please show the relevant code otherwise it is difficult to judge.

Comment: @a_guest Added the code as requested

Comment: The only problem seems that you are using `.weight` extention, which i have never seen. I may be wrong at this point. But have you tried using `.h5` extension.

Comment: @AnkishBansal That doesn't seem to solve the problem

Comment: @Skusku Can you please add the part of the code that instantiates `self.model` (and anything that happens in between that and `__init__`) as well as the output of `self.model.summary()`?

Comment: @a_guest I found the problem. Actually the saving and loading worked fine. I was working with an Annealed Epsilon Greedy Policy, so every time I started training, it would, at the start, do basically random steps only anyway. In addition, my Testing Code was wrong, so testing did not what it was supposed to do. These two combined made it feel like it would actually learn something (training went well) but didn't save the weights (testing went wrong, next training started from 'random').

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. Actually the saving and loading worked fine. I was working with an Annealed Epsilon Greedy Policy, so every time I started training, it would, at the start, do basically random steps only anyway. 
In addition, my Testing Code was wrong, so testing did not what it was supposed to do. These two combined made it feel like it would actually learn something (training went well) but didn't save the weights (testing went wrong, next training started from 'random').

Comment: could you please post the corrected code? I have the same problem.